# jQuery Mobile Event not firing with iOS7 Web Full Screen App

Tags: jquery, mobile, ios7

I have an iPhone web app which works fine in iOS7 Safari when operating in 'normal' mode but when I configure it to operate full screen the jQuery Mobile pageinit event doesn't seem to be fire.

This is how I set full screen:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

This is the jQuery Mobile I'm using:

```
$(document).delegate("#MyId", "pageinit", function () {
  alert('pageinit');
});
```

Have you found this problem?

Thanks
S

Comment: Turns out that the event is firing but there is an issue with alert() and iOS7.

Comment: See https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-event-not-firing-with-ios7-web-full-screen-app